# How to disable a material from writing to the z-buffer

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I want a particular material on my mesh to be transparent and not write to the z-buffer so that other parts of the same mesh can be seen through the material.

Here's a quick idea of the problem:
[image: plane with glass cockpit]

[image: inside the cockpit]

How might I make it so that I can see the cockpit internals through the glass from the outside?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. How are you rendering this? Why write to the Z buffer? Isn't a simple transparent material enough ?

Comment: If the goal is just to make a transparent material, enable Z-Transparency for the material and bring down the value for Alpha.